# Order of op amp cascade to reduce noise

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, gain

I am currently designing a little circuit to amplify a weak signal with two sequential op amps. To reduce the noise at the output of the two amplifiers, what would be the best order to place these amlifiers in? Should the amplifier with the highest gain be the first amplifier or the other way around?

Comment: How much gain there is and what op amps are you using? Usually the amplifier with less noise should be first.

Comment: Nemo, I believe just before and right at the first stage is ***everything***. Once you let the noise into the system, all that remains to you are bad choices between trade-offs. You don't say what your signal is, but let's say it's optical. Then you'd do ***everything*** possible ***before*** the optical signal hits a transducer and becomes electrical. Then, at the 1st stage you'd do everything possible there. The rest of the circuit is mostly a "no brainer." The real work is in what happens before, during the transducer conversion, and right at the 1st stage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I think I could have written it clearer, but what I meant was if it is better practice to have a low, or a high gain amplifier at the first stage to minimize the input noise.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you want to place the highest gain stage first:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbYDni.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To represent an amplifier's input noise, and any other noise that the signal may contain, I add noise N to the input signal S prior to it entering the first amplifier stage, with a gain of 100. Then I do the same with more noise N introduced at the input of the second stage, with a gain of 10.

The signal at X, is:

$$ X = 100 \cdot (S + N) $$

The signal at Y, the overall output is:

\begin{aligned}
Y &= 10 \cdot (X + N) \newline
&= 10 \cdot [100 \cdot(S + N) + N] \newline
&= 10 \cdot (100 \cdot S + 100 \cdot N + N) \newline
& = 1000 \cdot S + 1010 \cdot N
\end{aligned}

Now let's reverse the order of the stages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRnKk4.png)</sup>

The new expression for X becomes:

$$ X = 10 \cdot (S + N) $$

The overall output Y becomes:

\begin{aligned}
Y &= 100 \cdot (X + N) \newline
&= 100 \cdot [10 \cdot(S + N) + N] \newline
&= 100 \cdot (10 \cdot S + 10 \cdot N + N) \newline
& = 1000 \cdot S + 1100 \cdot N
\end{aligned}

It's pretty clear that putting the high gain stage last produces more overall noise, but this a generalisation based on a few assumptions that may not be true for any particular implementation. For instance,I've modelled the total noise as the linear weighted sum of two identical noise sources, which is somewhat naive.

Also, if for some reason the high gain stage introduces less noise than the low gain stage (has a lower noise figure), it makes more sense to place it early in the chain. My model here assumes that the main contribution of noise is the high gain stage, based solely on its gain, which may or may not be true, especially if you've used different quality gain elements, or the peripheral resistances around the high gain stage are of a significantly lower order.

It's always good to try to build *every* stage with the best noise figure possible, but it is less important for low gain stages *only* if they are late in the chain. This is because the earlier that a stage appears in the chain, the greater its noise contribution is overall, as I hope I've shown here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the amplifier with the lowest noise figure first.

It was suggested that I add some more meat to this statement.  So here it is.

The noise factor F (not figure) of an amplifier is a measure of how the the signal to noise ratio is degraded by that amplifier.  F is the ratio of the output SNR (signal to noise ratio) to the input SNR.  SNRout is always higher than SNRin because of the noise added by any real-world, non-ideal amplifier.

When you have multiple amplifiers in series, the noise factor contribution of amplifier N is reduced by the total gain of all the amplifiers before it.  If you have two amplifiers in series, A1 with gain G1 and noise factor N1, followed by A2 with gain G2 and noise factor N2, then the total noise factor for that amplifier chain is F1+(F2-1)/G1.  This is called the the Friis equation.

Finally noise figure is just the noise factor converted to dB.  Hence my recommendation that you put the amplifier with the lowest noise figure (factor) first in the chain.

Here's a link to a more detail explanation:
https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/noise-figure

Comment: While this is good advice, can you expand on this answer? One sentence answers aren't usually the most useful.

Comment: @user2943160 - good suggestion.  See edited answer.

Comment: Very nice! Might not be the best match up for the application, but the question could use some improvement, too.

Comment: Agreed, about the fact that the question could have been worded better, or more information provided.  If the OP had said "two op amps with the same noise figure but different gains", the answer could have better tailored.

Answer (score 0):

The Best would be that you add some schematics with some parts.

Rather than having 2 average opamps, you rather have 1 high-performance instrumentation amplifier.

Op-amp is only part of the output noise and you need to ensure you have the proper filters in place to cut everything you don't need as well as having a good PCB layout.

At least R-C filters before and after the opamp will help reduce the signal, if you drive an ADC you will need a [voltage follower opamp](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Voltage-follower) able to drive the ADC.